# PHP csv functions, Microsoft safe?

Tags: php, csv

I have been looking into the php fputcsv function, and have heard some comments that the files created using this method will not work on microsoft excel, is this correct?

**Comment on php.net**

> since PHP is generally *nix-based, it
>   makes sense that the line endings are
>   always \n instead of \r\n. However,
>   certain Microsoft programs (I'm
>   looking at you, Access 97), will fail
>   to recognize the CSV properly unless
>   each line ends with \r\n. Secondly, if
>   the first column heading / value of
>   the CSV file begins with uppercase ID,
>   certain Microsoft programs (ahem,
>   Excel 2007) will interpret the file as
>   being in the SYLK format rather than
>   CSV, as described here:
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323626

So

If i am planning on outputting data in the format of

0, 0278221234, 60143512345, 5pt code, yes
1, 0278221234, 60143512345, 5pt code, yes
2, 0278221234, 60143512345, 5pt code, yes
3, 0278221234, 60143512345, 5pt code, yes

also,

what is the difference between writing a file using this function

and simply creating the line's as above and ending them with \r\n ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> files created using this method will not work on microsoft excel, is this correct?

This is partially correct. MS Excel can read the files fine when the user uses the import wizard. But you'll want that the files to work without user knowing how you've made them -- that is, without using the import wizard.

To make the files work automatically, use ; (semicolon) as a record separator. E.g.

```
$data = array("one", "two", "three");
$fh = fopen('test.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fh, $data, ";");
fclose($fh);
```

Also note that in order to write UTF-8 to the CSV you'll have to add UTF-8 BOM to the beginning of the file.

Comment: Cheers, What does using the semi do as compared to the comma?
also, UTF-8 is not needed if i am only using 0-9 a-z correct?

Comment: @Hailwood: UTF-8 is identical to ASCII in the 0-128 range (which includes - amongst other things - a-z,A-Z, 0-9 and basic punctuation), and BOM is not strictly necessary anyway.

Comment: Hailwood, the semicolon is the separator character used in some region settings (such as Dutch). You can change this in the region settings in Windows if you'd want to.

Comment: Cheers Guys,
So any answer on the last part of the question? The difference on using the fputcsv function and creating a comma(or semi) seperated list and ending the lines with \r\n?

Comment: The difference with fputcsv is that it escapes the data, e.g. enclosure char (default "). You can write the CSV output with fwrite if you like.

Answer (score 0):

IF you have problems with Excel, you can always replace \n with \r\n once the file is created. It's like 4 more lines of code.

[edit]

Just tested with Excel 2007. Opens fine.